# Let $X$ be a binomial R.V. with parameters $n, p$. Use Chebyshev's inequality to bound $P(X < x)$.

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

If $x < \mu$, then Chebyshev's inequality can be used to bound $P(X < x)$, as shown by the following analysis: [Using Chebyshev's inequality, which gives a bound on $P(\mid X - \mu \mid \geq y)$ to bound $P(X > x)$ or $P(X < x)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3471390/using-chebyshevs-inequality-which-gives-a-bound-on-p-mid-x-mu-mid-geq-y)

Since $X$ is a binomial R.V., with parameters $n$ and $p$:

$$ \mu = np, \sigma^2 = np(1- p) $$

Let $x = \mu - y$, then $y = \mu - x$, and we have:

$$ P(X \geq x) \leq \frac{np(1 - p)}{y^2} = \frac{np(1 - p)}{(np - x)^2}$$

Finally, note that:

$$ P(X < x) = 1 - P(X \geq x) \geq 1 - \frac{np(1 - p)}{(np - x)^2}$$

In particular, suppose that $n = 100$, $p = 0.55$, and $x = 50$. The probability that $P(X < x)$ is:

$$ P(X < 50) = \sum_{k = 0}^{49} {100 \choose k}0.55^k(1 - 0.55)^{100 - k} \approx 0.135$$

Chebyshev's inequality does not really provide much information, since:

$$P(X < 50) \geq 1 - \frac{100 \times 0.55 \times (1 - 0.55)}{(x - 100 \times 0.55)^2} = 0.01$$

...which is true, since $0.135 > 0.01$. Have I made a mistake, or does Chebyshev's inequality not provide much information in this case?

Comment: You seem to essentially say at one stage that $P(|X-\mu|\ge y) = P(X-\mu\ge y)$, but that's not correct, is it?

Comment: Well, that's because $P(\mid X - \mu\mid \geq y) = P(-y \geq X - \mu \vee X - \mu \geq y)$, but since $y$ is positive, $-y \geq X$ (i.e. $X \leq -y$), can never happen, as $X$ would then be negative (the binomial distribution has positive support)?

Comment: @user89 $P(-y \geq X - \mu )=P(X \leq  \mu - y)$, now you argue in your previous comment that $\mu-y<0$. Is it right?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I heavily updated my work. Is it okay now?